# Mobile Beta testing and production versions installed along side on the same device

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, production-environment, beta-testing

**Context :**

It is a given, that in order to have both, beta and production vesions of any app, is to differentiate in their appids in a way :

com.company.app for production

com.company.app.beta or (something similar) for beta testing.

But this has forced me to provide different configurations for my push notifications as they are tied to the appid, this is fine by me.

My issue is with in-app purchases / billing.

Be it for iOS or android, the products are configured in the itunesconnect and play console respective app's home page.

Both of these pages are tied to the app id, and so i must create two apps on itunes connect and play console one for production and one for beta testing.

**My question :**

Is there any other way to go about having both version of an app installed along side in the same device and having a testable inapp purchases without creating the two aforementiond pages ?

Thanks, and sorry for being so verbose !

Comment: No, for having two installed side-by-side they have to have different packages

Comment: No it is not possible in a single device. Why don't you use two different devices?

Comment: Ok thank you, i would use different devices, it s just that my clients don t necessarily have this luxury, so in a way I m just asking for confirmation by other developers that the only route is to have different iTunes connect apps one for production and one for beta.